# how to select RadTreeView Node recursively based on node depth in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, telerik

I am able to find and select a Node using FindNodeByValue(string). However I want the logic to work based on the nodeDepth.

Since I do not want to create a case statement for each possible nodeDepth (for example one tree could have 2 levels while another tree could have 500) how do you dynamically FindNodeBYValue on the Correct Node[i]

```
    public void treeManageUsers_NodeClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    treeManageUsers.UnselectAllNodes();

    // Store companyID
    strID = e.Node.Value.ToString();
    Session["EntityID"] = strID;

    int nodeDepth = e.Node.Level;

    switch (nodeDepth) {
        case 0:
            treeManageUsers.Nodes.FindNodeByValue(strID).Selected = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            treeManageUsers.Nodes[0].Nodes.FindNodeByValue(strID).Selected = true;
            break;
    }

    //...
}
```

I am guessing some kind of recursion?

Comment: If the depth is 1, how do you know that you need to select the first node in the root node's children to find the collection with the item you're interested in?

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact scenario, it would appear as though you have already found the node you are looking for however when you use the code: int nodeDepth = e.Node.Level;  Where e.Node is the node you just clicked on.  Could you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TechneWare if I comment out the switch statement and click a node the node I clicked will not remain `selected`

Comment: Have your tried just using e.Node.Selected = true; ?